# Rails 5 app sharing the server and database with a Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails web app developed with Rails 4. Now I need to build an API using the same database because I want to develop a mobile apps that uses the same data.

I am not ready to upgrade my app from Rails 4 to 5, so I am thinking of creating a Rails 5 API app connected to same database, running on the same server.

Is it a good idea to have a Rails 4 app and a Rails 5 app sharing the same database and running on the same server?

Comment: "same server" means what exactly? if you are running them in the same process that won't work as you can not load gems in different versions.

Comment: "same server" I mean same linux server, same IP, I know it's possible to have several rails apps on one physical server, only I don't know if its good to have a rails 4 app and rails 5 api on same physical server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem running multiple versions of Rails on the same physical server, as long as you are using [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or something similar to manage different versions of Ruby, or you use the exact same version of Ruby on both. I would not recommend changing the version of Ruby on the older application unless you have a test suite, and you can't run Rails 5 with Ruby older than 2.2.2.

As far as connecting to the same database: Having multiple Rails applications using the same database is very difficult, because Rails expects to manage migrations on the database. If you keep the database migrations in your existing Rails application, how will you set up the database to run your tests in the new Rails application?

There are ways to do this, such as manual steps to bring in the migrations from the other project in order to run tests, but it adds a lot of complexity to your testing and development process. And make no mistake: *it is very important to have tests*.

I would recommend adding your API to the Rails 4 application using [Rails::Api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) or upgrading Rails in the older application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I guess I will upgrade my existing app to Rails 5 and than add API to it.